# Creating a Scrollable StackPanel Control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xaml

How would I create a control like the example at [this site](http://arcanecode.com/2007/09/12/scrolling-in-wpf/) as a User Control?

So, instead of doing this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <!– Content –>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I could do this:

```
<ScrollableStackPanel>
    <!– Content –>
</ScrollableStackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that as a UserControl in WPF.  You would need to make a custom control (instead of a user control) based on [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).  It could handle this correctly.

That being said, I don't see much point in this.  It's very easy to just put your StackPanel within a ScrollViewer - why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm trying to make a type of StackPanel that is scrollable and it's items are Drag n Droppable

Comment: Why not just use a ListBox or a StackPanel in a ScrollViewer?  Otherwise, you need to make a custom control - you can't have a user control be an ItemsControl (which lets you have multiple "content" elements)...

Comment: Reed is right. This is the entire point of WPF's separation of visual and behavioral aspects of controls. You wouldn't know by looking at them but a TabControl and ListBox are nearly the same exact control, both deriving from Selector. You should instead look into replacing ListBox's style and/or ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to use a ListBox. You can override the ItemContainterStyle and ListBox.Style to get rid of all the Selected behaviours and backgrounds if you want. Because a ListBox has StackPanel and ScrollViewer in it by default.